# Delete SQL - Taking forever

Tags: sql, oracle12c, dml

Delete SQL scripts are taking very long time and even hanging forever in Oracle 12c. We are having hundreds of delete scripts like below and even tried to run it by parallel operation /*+ PARALLEL (a,4) */ as well, but no luck in the performance improvement.

1. Is there any way to tune the delete scripts.
2. Can we use PL/SQL - for loop to make any performance improvement?
3. If yes, please share your thoughts and advices.

Some of Sample SQL Scripts:

```
DELETE 
FROM 
E_PROJ_DETAIL 
WHERE 
CATEGORY_ID in (SELECT PRIMARY_KEY FROM Y_OBJ_CATEGORY WHERE TREE_POSITION='VEN$_MADD');

COMMIT;

delete 
from 
e_proj_group_access
where enterprise_object_id in (select primary_key from t_project where application_id in (select application_id from y_object_definition where unique_code ='VEN$_MADD'));

commit;
```

Comment: how many rows in y_obj_category, how man in e_proj_detail?  does category_id have a index?  etc.  What you should do is look at the execution plan.

Comment: That's a tough one to answer without indepth detail (which you probably can't provide). My immediate thoughts: 1) there are index issues, 2) someone implemented a trigger somewhere which is slowing things down.

Comment: Related to @Paulb's guesses would be the question of whether there are unindexed foreign keys (which is a type of index issue but one that I'd call out separately).

Comment: Please give your DDL.

Comment: can you share execution plan pls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any possibility to 'tune' DELETE statements, maybe except droping any useless (=unused) indexes and constraints upfront and recreating them afterwards.

In these cases (deleting many rows) I used `FOR` loops with commits inside, something like this:

```
I := 0;
FOR c IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE [conditions to delete])
LOOP
    DELETE FROM table WHERE t.id = c.id; /* id = primary key */
    IF (I > 1000) THEN
        COMMIT;
        I := 0;
    END IF;
    I := I + 1;
END LOOP;
```

But here you can occasionally run into `ORA-01555: snapshot too old`, because you will delete rows from the same table from which you opened cursor in the `FOR` loop.

In other situations, you could do `CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT * FROM oldtable WHERE [conditions for rows I want to keep]` and then do `TRUNCATE oldtable` and `INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO oldtable SELECT * from newtable;` to write correct data back.

It really depends on the situation you are in (as others commented - how many rows do you have in the table, how many rows do you want to delete, etc.).

hth :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending if it is a one shot deal or not, creating a new table with only the rows you want to keep is often much faster :

```
CREATE TABLE E_PROJ_DETAIL_NEW AS 
SELECT * FROM 
E_PROJ_DETAIL 
WHERE 
CATEGORY_ID NOT IN (SELECT PRIMARY_KEY FROM Y_OBJ_CATEGORY WHERE TREE_POSITION='VEN$_MADD');
```

Then delete the old table and rename the new one.

You may need to re-create indexes / fk if you had some.